# Disable StringBuilder optimisation in javac

Tags: java, optimization, javac

When using normal string concatenation in Java, javac will optimise this where it can to use `StringBuilder` instead (or StringBuffer before Java 5.)

In my case, it'd be incredibly helpful to switch all this off, and just have string concatenation use the bog standard "append" method on `String` instead. Is this optimisation fully "baked in" to javac, or is there a way to disable it at all?

Comment: Why do you want to disable it?

Comment: What kind of "optimization" are you referring to? Or put differently: what kind of bytecode would you *want* string concatenation to produce?

Comment: @SimonC I'm writing a tool that creates a visualisation of student's Java code based on JDI events. When visualisations of StringBuilders pop up and they didn't actually use any, this can be confusing.

Comment: @berry120 Note that [the JLS allows a compiler to always replace concatenation by StringBuilders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1-120) (not saying that there is not an option that disables that, but it is not compulsory).

Comment: @berry120 But if you have source attached, can't you just find out from the sources if its actually StringBuilder usage or just plain String concat and act accordingly?

Comment: @SpaceTrucker Yes, it can. But this involves parsing the source, and thus is decidedly non trivial. It's probably the option I'll now look at, but if such an option *did* exist on javac itself it would have made my life much easier!

Comment: Wouldn't it be useful for the students to know what's actually going on under the hood with string concatenation?  I wish my colleagues were more aware of this so they didn't use a `StringBuilder` in exactly the same way the compiler would generate.

Comment: @SimonC Arguably in some cases, yes - and I plan to have an option for showing / hiding this behaviour, but right now that's not what I'm trying to achieve!

Comment: @berry120 have a look at the eclipse jdt api, which will give you correct source attachments and parsing, etc. - http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a javac expert but it seems to be hardcoded in javac in the [Gen.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/tl/langtools/file/a72412b148d7/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/jvm/Gen.java) file from line 1793.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to here - looks like there's definitely no way from that then. Onto some other options!

Comment: I'm neither a `javac` expert, but since *assylias* found the root of your problem, you could try to patch the `Gen.java`, making your own version of compiler. I don't know how deeply `Gen` is embedded, but you can either extend this class, or just simply modify and compile a new `Gen.class`, and replace in the appropriate system jar.

Answer (score 1):

Take alook at this [link](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_options.htm) its eclipse related but if your using eclipse you may find some configration related to optimizing options like unused local variables and co, hope you will find something helpful.

Alternatively [this assembler](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/) may help you It takes ASCII descriptions of Java classes, written in a simple assembler-like syntax using the Java Virtual Machine instruction set. It converts them into binary Java class files, suitable for loading by a Java runtime system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - unfortunately I'm just relying at present on the standard javac that comes with the standard JDK. May potentially have to change this at some point, but trying to hold off as long as I can!